# What is the sum of $H(CX+Y)$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, information-theory

Given that $X\sim\text{Bernoulli}(\nu)$, for some $\nu\in(0,1)$, and $Y\sim N(0,1)$ are **independent** random variables. What is the entropy $H(CX+Y)$, where $C$ is some fixed constant? I am a bit confused about how to derive this since we are adding discrete and continuous random variables together. Thanks.

Comment: How is continuous entropy defined, w.r.t. Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with measure theory. I guess we can treat the entropy of the sum as a differential entropy?

Comment: What is $C$ here?

Comment: Some fixed constant. Sorry... I've added it to the question.

Comment: $CX+Y$ is a measure that is not absolutely continuous w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure. Which means that you won't have the density w.r.t. the latter, hence differential entropy does not really apply here I guess.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help.